# Can't find REST DSL Component in RestConsumerFactory

Tags: java, apache-camel, undertow

I'm new to Camel and Java is not my main language, not sure what I'm doing wrong. I follow the camel's documentation to add a REST endpoint with restConfiguration to set up the components, host, and port first, then add the path.

```
@Component
public class MySpringBootRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        restConfiguration().component("undertow").host("localhost").port(7090);
        rest("/healthcheck")
            .get()
                .route()
                .to("direct:logging")
                .setBody(constant("Health check success!")).endRest();

        from("direct:logging")
                .log("Rest is running");
    }

}
```

In this code, I just have a simple healthcheck GET request. Even though, I added he dependency snippet to POM file, I'm having this error:
`No bean could be found in the registry for: undertow of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestConsumerFactory`.
I thought the componentid was wrong so I tried: "Undertow", "camel-undertow", but resulted with the same thing. I also tried using different components like jetty, netty, etc with added dependency to the POM.

The dependency looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change component input to "servlet" and it will use the underlying component